# Python: Expand 2D array to multiple 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, grid

Consider the followoing example from [np.meshgrid docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```py
nx, ny = (3, 2)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, nx)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, ny)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

In my application, instead of `x` and `y`, I've 25 variables. To create a grid out of the 25 variables, one way would be:

```
v1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
v2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
...
v25 = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)

z_grid = np.meshgrid(v1, v2, ..., v25)
```

However, the code will look ugly and not modular w.r.t. the number of variables (since each variable is hard-coded). Therefore, I am interested in something like the following:

```py
n_variables = 25
z = np.array([np.linspace(0, 1, 10)] * n_variables)
z_grid = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(z))
```

However, I am guessing `meshgrid(z)` is not the correct call, and I should expand `z` to `n_variables` arrays. Any thoughts on how I can expand the 2D array into multiple 1D arrays?

Comment: Are you sure you want a meshgrid that large?  10**25 is probably larger than your memory!  Try something smaller, say with 3 variables, and make sure the result are what you need.  Maybe you need to tell us what the bigger task is.

Comment: I need to walk in a 25 variable latent space; however, 25 is experimental, hence my method should be flexible on that.

Comment: What's a latent space?  meshgrid creates `n` arrays, each (n1,n2,...) in shape.  Beyond 3 variables memory uses gets out of hand.

Comment: Please see the example [here](https://tiao.io/post/tutorial-on-variational-autoencoders-with-a-concise-keras-implementation/), I would like to create a mesh grid of the size of the latent space of the VAE I'm creating. In other words, I'm trying to nodge the latent variables and see their impact on the decoder's output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65926752/901925 is an example of a memory error with just 6 dimensions.

Comment: Assuming the `n_variables` will be small enough for the resulting mesh to fit in the memory of my computer, do you know what is the correct syntax of passing the 2D array to `meshgrid`?

Comment: `meshgrid(*alist_of_arrays)`

Comment: Thank you! do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it.

```
n_variables = 25
z = np.array([np.linspace(0, 1, 10)] * n_variables)
z_grid = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(*z))
```

the * operator before list, unpacks list elements. consider following:

```
v1 = [1,2,3]
v2 = [4,5,6]
list_of_v = [v1,v2]
some_fucntion(v1,v2) == some_function(*list_ov_v)
```